# parametrize or loop through list for airflow

Tags: airflow

I have a list of lists lets say

```
import itertools
test_list = list(itertools.permutations([1, 2, 3]))
```

I want to create for every group of sublists a 
task in airflow like:

```
something_cool = PythonOperator(
  task_id='cool', 
  python_callable=do_something_cool(sub_list), 
  dag=dag)
```

would the best way to do this is to write a loop? in my case, the main list is very long and writing out each operator would be very hard.

Is there a way to hand an operator a list and have it parametrize it?

Answer (score 0):

iterating for loops work just fine with defining a task. just keep the whole def inside.. I have not tried dealing with dependencies.. which may not be possible.

dep can be set in a loop also. Wow I love airflow.

see https://www.astronomer.io/guides/managing-dependencies/